# Laravel ORM from self referencing table get N level hierarchy JSON

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using `LARAVEL 4` with `MySQL` back-end.

I have a `self-referencing` table with columns `id, name, type` and `parent`.
Here, `parent` is `foreign-key` of the column `Id`. The data in table is as below :

```
id  name          type         parent 
1   General       group        NULL
2   What is..?    question     1
3   aa            answer       2
4   bb            answer       2
5   cc            answer       2
6   How is..?     question     1
7   ba            answer       6
8   bb            answer       6
9   Where is..?   question     4
10  ca            answer       9
11  cb            answer       9
12  Who is..?     question     6
13  da            answer       12
14  db            answer       12
15  Specific      group        NULL
16  When is..?    question     15
17  ea            answer       16
18  eb            answer       16
19  Whome is..?   question     2
20  fa            answer       19
21  fb            answer       19
22  fc            answer       19
```

I want a function that return `nested JSON` using this relational data. For example :

```
[{
  "id" : 1, 
  "name" : "Geneal", 
  "type" : "group", 
  "children" : [{
      "id" : 2, 
      "name" : "What is..?", 
      "type" : "question", 
      "children" : [{
         "id" : 3, 
         "name" : "aa", 
         "type" : "answer"
      },
      {
         "id" : 4, 
         "name" : "bb", 
         "type" : "answer"
      },
      {
         "id" : 5, 
         "name" : "cc", 
         "type" : "answer"
      }]},
      {
      "id" : 6, 
      "name" : "How is..?", 
      "type" : "question", 
      "children" : [{
         "id" : 7, 
         "name" : "ba", 
         "type" : "answer"
      },
      {
         "id" : 8, 
         "name" : "bb", 
         "type" : "answer"
      }]
   }]
... and so on
}]
```

I have created a `model` named `Survey` as below :

```
class Survey extends BaseModel{

    protected $table = 'questions';
    protected $softDelete = false;

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Survey', 'parent');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Survey', 'parent');
    }   
}
```

and called it in `controller` with :

```
$user = Survey::all();
$parent = $user->parent()->first();
$children = $user->children()->get();
```

But I am not getting the proper result as I have mentioned in `JSON` above.

```
print_r($parent->toJson());
```

gives records with one level hierarchy only (i.e group and questions, not answers).

while

```
print_r($children ->toJson());
```

Gives only questions (Not groups and answers).

I want the whole **self-referencing data in nested JSON format with N level of hierarchy**.

I also have tried

```
$user = Survey::with('parent', 'children')->get();
```

But found same as $parent above.

Is there anyway I can get the desired result?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think LARAVEL is use-less framework. I am not finding any help anywhere in its document itself.

Comment: I think no experts available for LARAVEL on stackoverflow now

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/etrepat/baum

Comment: Read the docs http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading *nested relations*, try it, then come back if you still need help.

Comment: @deczo I already have mentioned in my question that I have used eager-loading. Please see $user = Survey::with('parent', 'children')->get(); This statement only retrieves group and questions, not answers. I want it as nested array or JSON with N level. How to achieve it?

Comment: @Dev I was talking about *nested relations*. Anyway check my answer

Comment: @deczo LARAVEL Experts are there on the stackoverflow - the amazing site.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here's how you manually retrieve nested relations:

```
$collection = Model::with('relation1.relation2.relation3')->get();
```

So in your case it would be:

```
$surveys = Survey::with('children.children.children')->get();
```

Obviously this will do the job when the relations are fixed, but it's not the way to go for a recursive relation to the same table.

Fortunately, **you can make such relation recursive**, then all you need to retrieve whole tree is this:

```
$surveys = Survey::with('childrenRecursive');
```

However, I wouldn't load parent for each row this way.

So here's all you need:

```
// Survey model
// loads only direct children - 1 level
public function children()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Survey', 'parent');
}

// recursive, loads all descendants
public function childrenRecursive()
{
   return $this->children()->with('childrenRecursive');
   // which is equivalent to:
   // return $this->hasMany('Survey', 'parent')->with('childrenRecursive);
}

// parent
public function parent()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('Survey','parent');
}

// all ascendants
public function parentRecursive()
{
   return $this->parent()->with('parentRecursive');
}
```

---

EDIT: To get real tree structure, first query must be limited to only root nodes:

```
$surveys = Survey::with('childrenRecursive')->whereNull('parent')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I am getting performance issue in this implementation. I have just 1047 records in this table still it takes too long to load this data (Almost 10 minutes, of course I have computer with good configuration.). There can be thousands of records in this table. In that case I assume it will not work. Have you any solution to increase performance?

Comment: I don't think it is giving me any array of table. There must be some error in recursion. I am getting 181415 rows for the call $surveys = Survey::with('childrenRecursive'); but none of this having any field of the table.

Comment: It's giving correct results, maybe you just exhausted your ram with 180 thousand item array.. Try with sensible limit.

Comment: OK. It might give the correct result but I cannot use it if it creates a performance issue. Is there any technique if you know to overcome this? I am novice to php especially laravel.

Comment: Loading 200 000 rows to an array will always cause memory issue. Process it in chunks, paginate or whatever. I can't suggest if I don't know what you do with that data.

Comment: I want to display it in treeview.

Comment: However, if I use $group = Survey::with('parent' ,'childrenRecursive')->get(); to get the records then it gives the desired result so fast but in that case I am finding problem of duplication with actual result. The duplicate child records are added at 0th level. Have you any solution for this? I think we are close to it.

Comment: Don't load `parent`. Duplicates are obvious, because you need to first select only root level rows. Check the edit.

Comment: Oh My GOD !!! It worked. :) Thank you so much.. It really worked.. Thanks for support. I am accepting this answer as well as +1 for your kind help. :) Thanks alot..

Comment: What if I want a column from another table to this model. For example there is a table named "template" which is referencing to the "survey" table with column "survey.template_id". Now I want the "template.title" column from "templates" table. How can I achieve it? I have tried left join but I haven't succeed.

Comment: Is it the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016893/get-column-of-other-table-in-laravel-orm-from-self-referencing-table-get-n-level/25030966#25030966 ?

Comment: Hmm.. I think so but I need to maintain the hierarchy (i.e. I have explained in this question. Will your link work the same?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by maintaining hierarchy. Anyway, check that related link, use `leftJoin`, and if it's not what you need, then ask a new question with proper description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have posted a new question with proper description. I request you to follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051501/laravel-eloquent-get-n-level-hierarchy-records-from-self-referencing-table-with and provide solution if possible.

Comment: can any one solve my same issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768670/illegal-offset-type-error-on-fetching-a-relations-to-self-class-in-laravel. I tried this answer but I got `Illegal offset type` error

Answer (score 3):

so simple!!!

1- load your 'children' relation in your 'children' relation in your model like this :

```
class Survey extends BaseModel{

    protected $table = 'questions';
    protected $softDelete = false;

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Survey', 'parent');
    }

    public function children()
    {
       // change this: return $this->hasMany('Survey', 'parent');

        return $this->hasMany('Survey', 'parent')->with('children);
    }   
}
```

2- you just need add **clouser** function to your relation like this:

```
$surveys = Survey::with(['children' => function($q) {
            $q->with('children');
       },
       'parent' => function($q) {
            $q->with('parent');
       });
```

then you can access to your nested children in your result like this:

```
$surveys->children
```

and unlimited nesting :

```
$surveys->children->first()->children
```

and so on.