# I am creating category model where it has parent of category model itself

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am creating category model where it has parent of category model itself..
i did the relations in model and its giving me output in json format. When i do

```
{{ $category->parent }}
```

it gives me :

```
{"id":1,"name":"test","slug":"test","parent_id":0,"is_active":0,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}
```

and if i try

```
{{ $category->parent()->name }}
```

it gives error ofcourse. 
any suggestions on how to fetch parent row object so that `$category->parent()->name` would work.

also in which scenario do we have to define table name in model as its working fine if i dont too.

=======================category model====================

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('name', 'slug', 'parent_id', 'is_active');
    public static $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'slug' => 'required',
    );

    public function parent(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'parent_id');
    }

   public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany('Category', 'parent_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: You may try `$category->parent->name` or `$category->parent()->get()->name`

Comment: @Razor `$category->parent->name` gives `Trying to get property of non-object` and $category->parent()->get()->name give `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name`

Comment: What's your relation function look like?  `{{ $category->parent }}` shouldn't be outputting the entire model's json.

Comment: @user3158900 please check the edits.

Comment: Some of your categories don't have a parent, they are root nodes, so you must check it `$category->parent` is not null first, then access its properties. `get()` returns collection, what you want is `first()` that returns single model.

Comment: Also, check this one since it's exactly the same scenario to what you're working on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672629/laravel-orm-from-self-referencing-table-get-n-level-hierarchy-json/24679043#24679043

Comment: @deczo yes you were right thank you .. but when i did this `{{ isset($category->parent) ? $category->parent()->get()->name : 'No parent' }}` its giving me `No parent` to even that has parent

Comment: @deczo also could you please write the answer where i can tick as correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your categories don't have a parent, they are root nodes, so you must check it `$category->parent` first, then access its properties.

Now, don't use `isset` since relation **is not** set as a property on the object. Use this instead:

```
if (count($category->parent)) // do something

// or is_null
if (is_null($category->parent));
```

---

Also `get()` returns collection, what you want is `first()` that returns single model.

I suggest you read this answer about **recursive relations** to make working with your setup easier:
[Laravel ORM from self referencing table get N level hierarchy JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672629/laravel-orm-from-self-referencing-table-get-n-level-hierarchy-json/24679043#24679043)

And also this one, so you know why I suggest `count` instead of `is_null` to check related model:
[Laravel check if related model exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910553/laravel-check-if-related-model-exists#answer-23911985)