# Get column of other table in Laravel ORM from self referencing table get N level hierarchy JSON

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have two tables `abc` and `def`. I have models of these two tables named respectively `Abc` and `Def`. In `Abc`, I declare these two functions:

```
public function child()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Abc', 'parent');
}

// recursive, loads all descendants
public function children()
{
   return $this->child()->with('children')->orderBy('sort_order');  
}

// parent
public function parent()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('Abc','parent');
}

// all ascendants
public function parentRecursive()
{
   return $this->parent()->with('parentRecursive');
}
```

In controllers I called these functions by

```
$abc = Abc::with('children')->whereNull('parent')->get();
```

I have implemented level hierarchy JSON from table through parent child relation. I have common column name in both tables. Through these method I get the title column of `abc` table. But I want to fetch title column of `def` table. How we can do this?

Comment: You didn't tell us, how the two are related, so it's impossible to suggest concrete solution. A guess would be: Use `joins`.

Comment: Thanks deczo....i have done this through                        $abc = Abc::with('children')
      ->leftJoin('def', function($join) {
        $join->on('abc.id', '=', 'def.abc_id');
      })
      ->whereNull('abc.parent')
      ->orderBy('sort_order', 'ASC')
      ->get([
       'abc.id',
       'def.title'
      ]);                                                             through this methods i got the title from def table for only parent row....but for chiild row i m not getting title from def table...it comes from abc table.

Comment: every `with` runs its own query, so you need to `join` that table every time, for each nesting level. I would rather use simple relation `Abc hasMany Def` in order to use eager load also that title from related object.

Comment: @deczo Can u please paste a sample code??

Answer (score 0):

Using relation:

```
// Abc model
public function defs()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Def', 'abc_id');
}

public function childrenWithDef()
{
  return $this->child()->with('childrenWithDef.defs')->orderBy('sort_order');
}

// then:
$abc = Abc::with('childrenWithDef', 'defs')->whereNull('parent')->get();

// every Abc has related Def collection
foreach ($abc->first()->defs as $def) $def->title
```

or manually joining on the relation and selecting  whatever you need:

```
public function childrenWithTitle()
{
   return $this->child()->with('children')->orderBy('sort_order')
     ->leftJoin('defs', 'defs.abc_id', '=', 'abcs.id')->select('abc.*', 'def.title');
}
```

Remember that you need keys/foreign keys to be selected in order to let Eloquent match children to their parents!

```
$abc = Abc::with('childrenWithTitle')->whereNull('parent')->leftJoin(...)->first();
$abc->childrenWithTitle->first()->title; // 'title' or null if no row found for this child
```

Comment: Will this make a separate database call to get title for each item?

Comment: Through this method i got only parent row...but not child with title of def table.so please suggest me...if  possible paste your code...

Comment: No, it will not make query per each item, but per nesting level. It should be `leftJoin`, maybe that was the problem. Check the edit in a sec with example code