# Eloquent Parent-Child relationship on same model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a model `CourseModule`, and each of the items are related to the same model.

## Database Structure:

[image]

## Relation in Model:

```
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CourseModule','parent_id')->where('parent_id',0);
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CourseModule','parent_id');
    }
```

I tried the following, but it returns only a single level of relation.

## Tried:

```
CourseModule::with('children')->get();
```

I'm trying to create a json output like the following,

## Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "course_id": "2",
    "name": "Parent",
    "description": "first parent",
    "order_id": "1",
    "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "parent_id": "1",
        "course_id": "2",
        "name": "Child 1",
        "description": "child of parent",
        "order_id": "2",
        "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "3",
            "parent_id": "2",
            "course_id": "2",
            "name": "Child2",
            "description": "child of child1",
            "order_id": "2",
            "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "4",
                "parent_id": "3",
                "course_id": "2",
                "name": "Child 3",
                "description": "child of child 2",
                "order_id": "2",
                "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
                "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I don't understand how to get the inner child objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would have to recursively get the children if you have an unknown depth like that.

Another option is to use the *nested sets model* instead of the *adjacency list model*. You can use something like `baum/baum` package for Laravel for nested sets.

> "A nested set is a smart way to implement an ordered tree that allows for fast, non-recursive queries." - https://github.com/etrepat/baum

With this package you have methods like `getDescendants` to get all children and nested children and `toHierarchy` to get a complete tree hierarchy.

[Wikipedia - Nested Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)

[Baum - Nested Set pattern for Laravel's Eloquent ORM](https://github.com/etrepat/baum)

[Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: Hi, `CourseModule::whereId($id)->first()->getDescendantsAndSelf()->toHierarchy()` returns only single node, should i have to make any changes to the model, i'm working with a single table as shown in top

Answer (score 34):

You should use `with('children')` in the children relation 
and `with('parent')` in the parent relations.

For your code to be recursive:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CourseModule','parent_id')->where('parent_id',0)->with('parent');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\CourseModule','parent_id')->with('children');
}
```

**Note:** Make sure your code has some or the other exit conditions otherwise it will end up in a never ending loop.

Comment: It works! In first collection I have a chained tree but in same children are repeated as parent collection. I don't want the children again as root collection. Is there any solution or am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found the solution `$data = CourseModule::with('children')->where('parent_id', 0)`

Comment: I am trying to display the results as the hierarchy, but could not.  I tried something like this `@foreach ($accountHeads as $accountHead)
                                        @foreach ($accountHead->children as $children)
                                            <option value="{{ $children->id }}">{{ $children->name }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endforeach` . But it showing only those, which has `parent_id` = `1` .

Answer (score 9):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24679043/4670278) is the answer that can help you

I think you you have to do it recursively to retrieve whole tree:

```
$data = CourseModule::with('child_rec');
```

## Recursive function

This may help you according to your requirement,

```
public function child()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\CourseModule', 'parent');
}
public function children_rec()
{
   return $this->child()->with('children_rec');
   // which is equivalent to:
   // return $this->hasMany('App\CourseModule', 'parent')->with('children_rec);
}
// parent
public function parent()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\CourseModule','parent');
}

// all ascendants
public function parent_rec()
{
   return $this->parent()->with('parent_rec');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Model Function:

```
public function Children()
{ 
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'Parent', 'Id')->with('Children');
}
```

Controller Function:

```
Menu::with("Children")->where(["Parent" => 0])->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

your model relationship should like this

```
     // parent relation
     public function parent(){

        return $this->belongsTo(self::class , 'parent_id');
    }
    //child relation
     public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class ,'parent_id');
    }
    public function ascendings()
    {
        $ascendings = collect();

        $user = $this;

        while($user->parent) {
            $ascendings->push($user->parent);

            if ($user->parent) {
                $user = $user->parent;
            }
        }

        return $ascendings;
    }



    public function descendings()
    {
        $descendings = collect();
        $children = $this->children;

        while ($children->count()) {

            $child = $children->shift();

            $descendings->push($child);

            $children = $children->merge($child->children);

        }
        return $descendings;
    }
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can always create your own recursive function, in my case I do as the code as follow.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Akmeh\Uuid;

/**
 * Class Location
 * @package Domain\Models
 */
class Location extends Model
{
    use Uuid;

    /**
     * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * @param string $id
     * @param array $tree
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getTree(string $id, array $tree = []): array
    {
        $lowestLevel = Location::where('id', $id)->first();

        if (!$lowestLevel) {
            return $tree;
        }

        $tree[] = $lowestLevel->toArray();

        if ($lowestLevel->parent_id !== 0) {
            $tree = Location::getTree($lowestLevel->parent_id, $tree);
        }

        return $tree;

    }

}
```