# Illegal offset type error on fetching a relations to self class in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My `User` model is like this :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'password',
        'name',
        'family',
        'supervisor'
    ];

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\User::class, 'supervisor', 'user_id')->with('children');
    }

}
```

As you can see there a `supervisor` column that specify parent of a user.

Now to fetch all children of user models that have `supervisor= null`, I wrote this :

```
return User::with('children')->whereNull('supervisor')->get();
```

but it return this error always :

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type in D:\wamp\www\zarsam-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany.php on line 168
```

Table users have these data :

```
+---------+-------------+---------+--------------+------------+
| user_id |  username   |  name   |    family    | supervisor |
+---------+-------------+---------+--------------+------------+
|       1 | 09139616246 | ahmad   | badpey       | null       |
|       7 | alinasiri   | ali     | nasiri arani | 1          |
|       8 | zahedi      | mostafa | zahedi       | 1          |
|       9 | hsan        | hasan   | ghanati      | 8          |
+---------+-------------+---------+--------------+------------+
```

**Update :**

I found that problem is that I have a accessor same name `supervisor` attribute like this :

```
public function getSupervisorAttribute($value)
{
    return is_null($value) ? null : User::select('user_id', 'name', 'family')->find($value);
}
```

I added that because I want to return **supervisor** user as an object.
But now in this case, what do I do ?

Comment: Why do you use `->with('children')` in your `children` relation?

Comment: for my code to be recursive. based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/35768829/498504

Comment: Either confirm your version of Laravel or show line 168 of HasOneOrMany.php so we can see what Eloquent is trying to do.

Comment: I'm using `laravel 5.5.21`. this is line 168 : `protected function buildDictionary(Collection $results)
    {
        $foreign = $this->getForeignKeyName();

        return $results->mapToDictionary(function ($result) use ($foreign) {
            return [$result->{$foreign} => $result]; // line 168
        })->all();}`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this setup:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\User::class, 'supervisor', 'user_id'); 
}
```

And fetching them like

```
return User::with('children.children')->whereNull('supervisor')->get();
```

If this doesn't resolve your issue, then your `relationships` are not well defined, then I suggest reading about `foreign`and `local` keys inside your `children.children` model

**NOTE:**

**HasOneOrMany.php**

```
...
return $results->mapToDictionary(function ($result) use ($foreign) { //line in question
...
```

And when I found that method, this is what it said:

```
/**
 * Run a dictionary map over the items.
 *
 * The callback should return an associative array with a single key/value pair.
 *
 * @param  callable  $callback
 * @return static
 */
public function mapToDictionary(callable $callback)
```

I want to point out **`The callback should return an associative array with a single key/value pair.`** Which means you cannot do it `recursively`, at least I believe you can't.

Comment: while `children.children` can fetch only 2 levels of children of a supervisor user, it return same error again.

Comment: Even I tried  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24679043/498504) , but I got same error. I'm full confused