# Pulling all categories and grouping them by parent id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, eloquent-relationship

I am working with Laravel data querying and I need a query that is going to group all the children of a parent when I take the categories.

the categories table has a name and a parent_id, the routes of the categories have the parent_id set as null, the query should return every category grouped by parent id and the parent should be the first node of every group.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758965/eloquent-parent-child-relationship-on-same-model

Comment: this is not a nested set, the max depth will be parent and child, so depth is one.

Comment: @EndritSheholli Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to display the categories as parent child somewhere, you do not need to collect them like that, you can make a relationship within the model like

```
class Category {
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

may be it will be one-to-many relationship instead of many-to-many depending on your requirement.

Now you can just get all the parents like

```
Category::whereNull('parent_id')->get();
```

or using a scope

`Category::parent()->get();` and define the scope in the model

and loop through the parent category like

```
@foreach ( $categories as $category ) 
       {{ $category->name }}
       @foreach ( $category->children as $subCategory )
           {{ $subCategory->name }}
       @endforeach
@endofreach
```

and to retrieve parent with children you can use

```
Category::whereNull('parent_id')->with('children')->get();
```

or

```
Category::parent()->with('children')->get();
```

I have not tested the code, but roughly it will be like this.

Answer (score 0):

contoller

```
$locations   = OurLocation::groupBy('country_id')->with('children')->get();
```

model

```
public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OurLocation::class, 'country_id','country_id');
    }
```

blade

```
@foreach($locations as $index=>$location)
  @foreach($location->children as $children)
        {{ $children->company_name }} <br>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -2):

When you get the returned collection from the query, you are able to use the [->groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby) method where you can specify the field which the results should be grouped by.

Assuming your categories model is `Category`:

```
$categories = Category::all()->groupBy('parent_id')->toArray();
```

Comment: this does not return a nested collection. It groups all categories with no parent, then all categories with parent_id 1, etc. OP: `should return every category grouped by parent id and the parent should be the first node of every group`