# Recursive Eloquent Models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I have a Message::class for which I want to get thread messages for each particular message.

how can I recursively fetch messages and messages of messages etc. etc. using Laravel and Eloquent::hasMany

So far I tried setting up a recursive on the hasMany()

```
public function replys()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'reply_to', 'id');
}

public function replies()
{
    $r = $this->replys;
    if(count($r->get('replys')) > 0){
      foreach($r->get('replys') as $reply) {
        $r->push(Message::create($reply)->replies());
      }
    }

    return $r;
}
```

But I seem to be missing the mark. At the moment I'm trying to see if I can use a pivot table and reference `belongsToMany` . Will let yo know how things progress

Comment: How about creating a thread model, where each thread can have many messages and messages belong to a single thread.

Comment: @tam was thinking the same thing. Was wondering if i should create a pivot table and work my way backwords using `belongsToMany` had to jump off of it for a while but will post findings soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Research led me to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672629/laravel-orm-from-self-referencing-table-get-n-level-hierarchy-json) that suggested how to get recursive records via `hasMany`

thus

```
public function replys()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'reply_to', 'id');
}

public function replies()
{
  return $this->replys()->with('replies');
}
```

Did not think it would be this easy however, I was hoping that I could have kept it simple without having to devise a complex raw query statement.

My question now is how does this recursive method stand up to large data sets?