# Laravel 9 - Eloquent model : Trying to load self model parents recursively

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I'm trying to migrate a **Laravel 5** API with MySQL 5.7 to a **Laravel 9** API with MySQL 8.

Almost everything is working well, except on a few queries that tries to load data with their parent, recursively.

On Laravel 5, i came up with this following solutions : [Recursive Eloquent Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173630/recursive-eloquent-models/41187333#41187333) | [Laravel ORM from self referencing table get N level hierarchy JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672629/laravel-orm-from-self-referencing-table-get-n-level-hierarchy-json/24679043#24679043)

It was working like a charm, but on Laravel 9, I get a HTTP 500 error from Apache, which tells me in the logs the following error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
> (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)

I tried at first to increase the memory in php.ini, but it was getting worst as the server was getting very laggy, so I had to restart Apache and go back with the 128M default value. Also on my Laravel 5 environment, I did not need to increase memory.

I was also suspecting the MySQL 8 upgrade to be involved in this problem, but by connecting to my MySQL 5.7 database, i had the same issue, so I think it comes from the way that Laravel loads relations in the 9 version.

Here is my Model code :

```
<?php
  namespace App\Models\Consommation;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class ConsoRequestAttribut extends Model
  {
    protected $table = 'conso_request_attribut';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_attribut';
    public $timestamps = false;

    const ERROR_DELETE_ATTRIBUTE = 1;
    const SUCCESS_DELETE_ATTRIBUTE = 0;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_attribut',
        'code_type_attribut',
        'valeur',
        'id_parent_attribut'
    ];

    public function parent_attribut() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Consommation\ConsoRequestAttribut', 'id_parent_attribut', 'id_attribut');
    }

    public function parent() {
        return $this->parent_attribut()->with('parent');
    }

    ...
   }
```

So on my Laravel 9 app, if I remove the `->with('parent')` in my `parent()` function, the query result is returned and I don't have a 500 HTTP error, so I think the problem is with recursive loading.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not succeed to load the parent entity recursively with my `ConsoRequestAttribut` model, as I'm still stuck with the same memory problem. So it's not really "resolved".

As an alternative, in my `ConsoRequestAttributRepository` class, I made a function to load parent of entity recursively, which works perfectly :

```
public function retrieveRecursivelyConsoRequestAttributeParent(ConsoRequestAttribut $attribut)
{
    $parent = ConsoRequestAttribut::where('id_attribut', $attribut->id_parent_attribut)
        ->first();

    $attribut->parent = $parent;

    if($parent->id_parent_attribut != null)
        $this->retrieveRecursivelyConsoRequestAttributeParent($parent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to call nested relationships like this:

```
public function parent() {
    return $this->with('parent_attribut.parent');
}
```

Comment: does this solve the question ? I dont think so.

Comment: If i use your code in my model I get the following error :
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::addEagerConstraints()"`. 
It seems that this error pops up because this is not a relation?

Comment: I think so. Are you sure you have the `parent` relationship in `ConsoRequestAttribut` model?

Comment: Yes I have replaced my `parent()` function with yours and this error is throwed. 
Or do you mean that I need to have something else in my `ConsoRequestAttribut` model in addition to that ?

Comment: Wait I just realized that you have defined relationship in the same model. It means your table related to itself? If so, then what is `parent` relationship you have defined in `with('parent')`? It looks like a recursive function not even relationship

Comment: Yes that's a recursive function indeed and yes the table is related to itself !
Here is what the data returned looks like on my Laravel 5 app : https://img.onl/RXOoLk

Comment: Hmm, so strange. I can't say anything without debugging  it to deeper. It is better to use `debugbar` package to see actual sql query. It may be lazy loaded so you are getting `memory size exhausted` exception. Sorry I don't have any other idea